# C# WPF Anchoring Image control to only scale horizontally

Tags: c#, wpf, image, width, anchor

I have a problem using the Image control. I want to anchor the Image at the top of the window, with height 9 and whenever I resize my window, the image will shrink/grow, but ONLY horizontally. The reason I want to scale it only horizontally is because the image is supposed to be an opaque shape that gives a little style to the window, but the .png dimensions are 24x9, so I want to scale the image to 544x9, or whatever width value it may be.

My question is, how do I do it without loosing any quality?

Here's the code:

```
<ui:LauncherWindow x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:LauncherUI;assembly=LauncherUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="800" Width="1400" MinWidth="700">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="8">
            <Button Margin="95,0,95,0">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Border>
                                        <TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock.Background>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="border_topbar.png" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"/>
                                            </TextBlock.Background>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</ui:LauncherWindow>
```

Comment: *"without loosing any quality"*? Can you be more specific about what you mean by quality? If you're starting out with a 14x9 PNG, you only have fourteen pixels from left to right. If you try to stretch out those 14 pixels to fill 1400 pixels, it'll have to interpolate.

Comment: Well, it's just that the shape is a trapezoid and the upper side of the trapezoid is always longer than the lower side of the trapezoid, but it keeps increasing when resizing the window, thus creating blur.

Comment: Otherwise known as "interpolation". Try replacing the image with a vector graphic: `<Path 
                        Fill="LightSkyBlue" 
                        Data="M 0,0 L 14,0 L 12,9 L 2,9 Z" 
                        Height="9"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        />` for example. That'll stretch without interpolating. You'd have to make your textblock transparent though, and put that behind it, superimposed, in a grid or something.

Comment: If a vector graphic won't do the job (not knowing what your image looks like, I can't be sure), consider making an image that's as wide as you'll ever need, and letting the UI shrink it. You can't add pixels that were never there, but you can chuck out the old ones all you like.